# UISegmentedControl segment width of is not set when the background image is set

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control and I want first and last items to be of specified width (say, wider than others). When I `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:` for standard-styled segmentedControl (i.e. `[[UISegmantedControl appearence] setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:]` not set), things behave themselves as they should. But when I set background image, segments width doesn't change.

Here is my code:

```c
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:25 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_selected.png"]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:25 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nn.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sn.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ns.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[self.segmentedControl setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.segmentedControl setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:4];
```

With this, all my segments appear automatically sized to the equal width.
And when I comment out all above this

```c
[self.segmentedControl setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[self.segmentedControl setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.segmentedControl setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:4];
```

the sizes are set correctly.
Here is my question: how can I set sizes for the segments with background images?
I'm new to cocoa-touch and objective-c, so I might be missing something...
Could you help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think when you use **[UISegmentedControl appearance]** proxy it overrides **"setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:"** method values. So possible solutions:

1)

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:4];
```

I would not recommend to use this because it will set custom width for 0 and 4 segments for every segmented control in your app.

2)

```
[self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:25 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_selected.png"]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:25 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nn.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sn.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ns.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you need that all segmented controls in your app should have custom background then I would recommend to write your own proxy method. Something like this:

```
- (UISegmentedControl *) customSegmentedControl {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [ [ [UISegmentedControl alloc] init] autorelease];

    [segmentedControl setBackgroundImage: [ [UIImage imageNamed: @"btn_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 25 topCapHeight: 0] forState: UIControlStateNormal barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmentedControl setBackgroundImage: [ [UIImage imageNamed: @"btn_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 25 topCapHeight: 0] forState: UIControlStateSelected barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmentedControl setDividerImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"nn.png"] forLeftSegmentState: UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState: UIControlStateNormal barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmentedControl setDividerImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"sn.png"] forLeftSegmentState: UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState: UIControlStateNormal barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmentedControl setDividerImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"ns.png"] forLeftSegmentState: UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState: UIControlStateSelected barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];

    return segmentedControl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Igor!
But that my question was about sizing of the segments. 
I solved this problem by writing custom control.

Comment: @voiger, Igor is right. By setting the background image on the actual instance rather than on the appearance instance, setting the widths on the individual segment works. It's only when you apply a background image via the appearance does it ignore the specified widths. This appears to have been fixed in iOS 6.0, so it's only broke on iOS 5.0 currently.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by writing custom control, based on this http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/11/custom-segmented-controls/